# extending QSpinBox ContextMenu

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

Feel like I have looked everywhere but can't find an answer to this.
Was wondering if there is a way to add extra QActions to a QSpinBox ContextMenu?
Ideally to the top of the list of actions.

I know you can replace the default menu as shown below, but can figure out how to extend:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class QSpinBox(QtGui.QSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        QtGui.QSpinBox.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
        self.resize(200, 60)

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.__contextMenu)

    def __contextMenu(self):
        self._normalMenu = self.build_menu()
        self._normalMenu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())

    def build_menu(self):
        self.menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)

        self.save = QtGui.QAction("Save", self)
        self.menu.addAction(self.save)

        self.reset = QtGui.QAction("Reset", self)
        self.menu.addAction(self.reset)

        return self.menu


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = QSpinBox()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Default menu:

[image]

Options I would like to add to the top:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to get the `QMenu` a moment after it is displayed using `findChild()` with `QTimer.singleShot()`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class SpinBox(QtGui.QSpinBox):
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.on_timeout)
        super(SpinBox, self).contextMenuEvent(event)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_timeout(self):
        menu = self.findChild(QtGui.QMenu, 'qt_edit_menu')
        if menu is not None:
            first_action = menu.actionAt(QtCore.QPoint())
            save_action = QtGui.QAction(
                "Save", 
                menu, 
                shortcut=QtGui.QKeySequence.Save,
                triggered=self.on_save_triggered
            )
            reset_action = QtGui.QAction(
                "Reset", 
                menu, 
                triggered=self.on_reset_triggered
            )
            menu.insertAction(first_action, save_action)
            menu.insertAction(save_action, reset_action)
            menu.insertSeparator(first_action)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_save_triggered(self):
        print("save")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_reset_triggered(self):
        print("reset")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = SpinBox()
    w.resize(600, w.sizeHint().height())
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```